# Let NCAlgebra know that Tr[] commutes

Tags: ncalgebra

I have an expression  where there are terms like

```
a ** (b*Tr[a ** b])
```

and I want to simplify it to something like

```
Tr[a ** b]a ** b
```

How can it be done? I have tried with `NCExpand` and haven't worked.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is "cyclic".

Comment: I mean, it is cyclic in the argument but the result is an scalar and it then commutes, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my edits for my earlier submission.

Comment: Can you edit your posted answer with this? That is the better way to do this. If not, I suggest you do this or post this as a comment. It might be helpful if you included a successful test input/output, also.

Comment: Ok, it worked even though I had to unprotect the symbol Tr with Unprotect[Tr], which could be risky isn't it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Edited:
The command `SetCommutative[Tr]` forces all of the expressions whose head is Tr to be considered commutative.

If necessary, you can use
`UnProtect[Tr];SetCommutative[Tr];Protect[Tr];`.

Another solution is `Tr/:CommutativeQ[Tr[x_]] := True;`

Comment: Shouldm't it be the other way around? SetCommutative[Tr] . Either way it doesn't work for me. With  SetNonCommutative[Tr] I get WARNING: Symbol Tr is protected. You should seriously consider not setting it as noncommutative and with SetCommutative[Tr] I get UpSet::write: Tag Tr in CommutativeQ[Tr] is Protected.

Comment: Got the answer backward. See the other solution which I posted.

Answer (score 1):

In NCAlgebra, expressions are considered commutative only if the Head and all arguments are commutative. That is why using `SetCommutative[Tr]` will fail in this case. If `Tr` is commutative, `Tr[x]` will still be noncomutative if x is noncommutative. However, I would not recommend that you add rules to `CommutativeQ`. That can become messy. Instead use the brand new command `SetCommutativeFunction` which is available with the version 5.0.6 of NCAlgebra. I would also discourage you from using the built in protected symbol `Tr`. For example,

```
SetCommutativeFunction[trace];
a ** (b*trace[a ** b])
```

would evaluate to

> trace[a ** b] * a ** b

as you want. By the way, I also implemented an operator `tr` that has the properties of the standard matrix trace. You might want to give it a try.